# Is it possible to create a texturepack for non-existing items/blocks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What I exactly wanted to ask: every item in minecraft has it's own ID and SubID

For example:
1:2 (where 1 is ID and 2 is subid)
wool:3 (where wool is ID and 3 is subid)
and etc.

Can I create a resourcepack that will contain textures for non-existing subids?
For example 1:102, 101:500 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't add new blocks using just a resource pack, since the game doesn't get the block IDs from there. You'd still need to tell minecraft what block your resources are about.

---

You have other options:

- Use Forge or similar and make a small mod to include your block(s). This requires at least some basic Java knowledge. ([Here](https://bedrockminer.jimdo.com/modding-tutorials/basic-modding-1-7/first-block/) is an example tutorial)
- Customize existing blocks using a resource pack.
- Make use of a [block designer](https://codecrafted.net/blockdesigner) (which requires a special resource pack).

Comment: Yep, block designer is what I actually needed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily, but you can change the texture of the 'texture not found' texture, which is the black and purple checkered texture you get on an item that has an unknown block id. But you cannot create new block ids with a texture pack, you need mods for that. You can look up a minecraft modding tutorial or if you just need to make a "new block" that you can't place then you can just use the 'texture not found' texture (although keep in mind that the texture is larger than other blocks, so you may be better off just looking up a modding tutorial).

Comment: Nice idea, but it will not work for my situation.